# How to limit select list - to select only one item in KnockoutJS

Tags: jquery, css, list, select, knockout.js

How to limit select list to select only one item? 
Can it be done through css?

```
<select multiple data-bind="options: Items,             
                   optionsText: 'Title',
                   value: selectedItems, optionsValue: 'Id',
                   attr: { name: 'item' }"></select>


<div data-bind="text: selectedItems"></div>



function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;  
    var    selection = [];
    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray();
    self.Items = ko.observableArray([{"Id": "0",  "Title": "Item1"}, 
    { "Id": "1", "Title": "Item2"}, { "Id": "2", "Title": "Item3"}]);    
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s95wezu2/1/

Comment: Can you explain in once sentence what the `multiple` attribute does?

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSS or Knockout. Just know what the multiple attribute does https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of your requirement. You can use the `size` attribute instead of `multiple`. This will restrict the user from selecting multiple options but will display all the options.

```js
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;  
    var    selection = [];
    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray();
    self.Items = ko.observableArray([{"Id": "0",  "Title": "Item1"}, 
    { "Id": "1", "Title": "Item2"}, { "Id": "2", "Title": "Item3"}]);    
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select size = 3 data-bind="options: Items,             
                   optionsText: 'Title',
                   value: selectedItems, optionsValue: 'Id',
                   attr: { name: 'item' }"></select>


<div data-bind="text: selectedItems"></div>
```

You don't need CSS for this.